# How can I extract a value from different large object files and use them in my XML payload?

Tags: jmeter

I have 2 sampler requests:

1. First request gets me a json response with different file names (large object files with XML contents) along with file paths. Example:
   c:\My_Folder_1\File-1.lob
   c:\My_Folder_2\File-2.lob
   (20 different .lob files with XML contents and file names/paths vary each time)
   I am trying to go to each of these files, extract a particular value
2. Use the above values in my payload XML (second request).

I have extracted all the file name/path values from Step-1 via RegEx. How can I iterate and go to each of these .lob files (xml), strip out all the contents except a particular value (with a specific tag ID) which I extract and use it my payload as part of step-2?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I iterate and go to each of these .lob files

[ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)

> strip out all the contents except a particular value

[HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler with `file` protocol and [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/xpath-extractor-jmeter)

> use it my payload as part of step-2

XPath Extractor gives you [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)(s) which can be used elsewhere